# How to filter out observations in R?

Tags: r

I am new to R and learning how to code.  Right now I have a dataframe from dslab called heights and it looks like this:

```
    Sex    Height
1   Male     75
2   Male     70
3   Male     68
4   Male     74
5   Male     61
6   Female   65
```

However, now I want to filter out the male observations and put the female observations into a new dataframe.  How do I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `==` to get a logical vector which can be used for subsetting using `[`.

```
i <- x$Sex == "Male"

(male <- x[i,])
#   Sex Height
#1 Male     75
#2 Male     70
#3 Male     68
#4 Male     74
#5 Male     61

(female <- x[!i,])
#     Sex Height
#6 Female     65
```

Data:

```
x  <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="    Sex    Height
1   Male     75
2   Male     70
3   Male     68
4   Male     74
5   Male     61
6   Female   65")
```